# Thread Stack Size Not Matching Native Memory Tracking Thread Stack Size

Tags: java, memory, tomcat7, maven-3, native

I'm currently doing some testing of memory settings on a Maven Tomcat7 plugin.  I'm setting the Thread Stack Size to 128k with the following:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -Xss128k
```

After that, I run jcmd with Native Memory Tracking Option  I get the following output.

```
C:\Users\gdrocell>jcmd 8672 VM.native_memory summary
8672:

Native Memory Tracking:

Total: reserved=9995213KB, committed=1283517KB
-                 Java Heap (reserved=8282112KB, committed=868864KB)
                            (mmap: reserved=8282112KB, committed=868864KB)

-                     Class (reserved=1103777KB, committed=59857KB)
                            (classes #9079)
                            (malloc=10145KB #11226)
                            (mmap: reserved=1093632KB, committed=49712KB)

-                    Thread (reserved=15844KB, committed=15844KB)
                            (thread #25)
                            (stack: reserved=15616KB, committed=15616KB)
                            (malloc=72KB #132)
                            (arena=156KB #48)

-                      Code (reserved=253665KB, committed=23761KB)
                            (malloc=4065KB #6562)
                            (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=19696KB)

-                        GC (reserved=313042KB, committed=288418KB)
                            (malloc=10386KB #203)
                            (mmap: reserved=302656KB, committed=278032KB)

-                  Compiler (reserved=152KB, committed=152KB)
                            (malloc=21KB #204)
                            (arena=131KB #3)

-                  Internal (reserved=10653KB, committed=10653KB)
                            (malloc=10589KB #10938)
                            (mmap: reserved=64KB, committed=64KB)

-                    Symbol (reserved=13705KB, committed=13705KB)
                            (malloc=10756KB #102196)
                            (arena=2949KB #1)

-    Native Memory Tracking (reserved=2065KB, committed=2065KB)
                            (malloc=7KB #85)
                            (tracking overhead=2058KB)

-               Arena Chunk (reserved=197KB, committed=197KB)
                            (malloc=197KB)
```

As you can see, the thread stack size seems to be 15.25mb.  Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Please tag your question with appropriate language / framework tags. The existing tas are not particularly useful.

Comment: Tags added.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this blog (https://blogs.oracle.com/saas-fusion-app-performance/how-to-set-stack-size-to-overcome-javalangstackoverflowerror)

> If it is not possible to change the stack requirements of the
>   application, you can change the thread stack size by using the -Xss
>   command-line option.

This is an stack size per thread. The figure you mention will vary with the number of threads.

**EDIT**

That is a lot of threads around 120. I would use -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=detail. To see if the info makes more sense

Comment: When I looked at the detailed summary, it turned out that some of the internal jvm threads were allocating more memory.  Internal thread size can be controlled by -XX:ThreadStackSize=N, but it seems the minimum for N is 1 MB. -Xss only controls thread stack size of threads spawned from main.

Comment: I think one of the docs I read mentioned the 1MB versus smaller argument. Thanks!